# Copy a directory from remote resource using Chef

Tags: chef

I want to copy a directory from a remote respository. To copy a single setup/file I am using remote_file resource. but this doesn't work if you want to copy a complete directory. I also checked chef's remote_directory resource, but that can be used only if the directory is in the cookbook itself. Any ideas as how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Create an archive for the files and transfer the archive using remote_file.

Comment: yea, I too thought of that solution. My client is on a windows 2008r2 system, and there's no native way to archieve a directory in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no portable way of listing the remote files to download (or is there?), a more specific approach has to be taken, such as running a [script](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_script.html) or [remote_file](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_remote_file.html) resource, or using the '[artifact](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/artifact)' cookbook to download and extract an archive.